# "Publish" programmatically on Azure Data Factory through powershell or Azure Devops pipeline step

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

This question won't have any code because I haven't found any possible way so far but not even a straight **no, it's not possible**.

Azure Data Factory uses **adf_publish** branch as the official branch on top of the master.
ADF publishes the definitions of all the pipelines, triggers, linked services, etc to this adf_publish branch when on the GUI the user clicks on **Publish**.

I need to do this programmatically. I don't want someone to go on the ADF portal itself and click on the Publish button so that the adf_publish branch is updated correctly. I need to know if there is some powershell code (or step in Azure Devops pipeline) that allows me to do this. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**:

After Kevin's answer below I gave it a try with the suggested powershell script and seems succeeding but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to do. Whenever I try to "Publish" from the ADF portal I see that it gathers the changes from the collaboration branch (Master) and tries to merge them in the Adf_Publish branch. An example is the pic below listing all the changes that will be merged.

[image]

So in theory the powershell script should do the same or that's what I am trying to achieve while instead it seems not doing anything:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT please check out the comment on your answer and also my update to show you what's going on when implementing your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could refer to [this ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53444) in Github.

You could install `Az.DataFactory` and `azure.datafactory.tools` PowerShell modules, then you could run the `Publish-AdfV2FromJson` method to publish.

Here is Azure Devops example:

```
variables:
  ResourceGroupName: 'rg-devops-factory'
  DataFactoryName: 'SQLPlayerDemo'
steps:
- powershell: |
   Install-Module Az.DataFactory -MinimumVersion "1.7.0" -Force
   Install-Module -Name "azure.datafactory.tools" -Force
   Import-Module -Name "azure.datafactory.tools" -Force
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     Publish-AdfV2FromJson -RootFolder "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ArtifactName_/" -ResourceGroupName "$(ResourceGroupName)" -DataFactoryName "$(DataFactoryName)" -Location "$(Location)" -Stage "$(Release.EnvironmentName)"

    FailOnStandardError: true
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this introduction document](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools#using-azure-powershell-task)

On the other hand, you could use the out of the box task: `Publish Azure Data Factory` from [Deploy Azure Data Factory by SQLPlayer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.. had time to investigate over the problem only lately. it seems that the script works or at least it completes without problem. However I would expect that whenever I publish (in this case programmatically) the Adf_publish branch gets updated in Git too. This is at least what happens when I publish from the portal and confirms me that indeed the publish succeeded. But when I publish through this script it doesn't happen :/

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible and quite an expected requirement in real world case. Please go through [Continuous integration and delivery in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment). It's too long guide to put it as an answer in short, so you have to read that in details :). Below is just a short quote of the scenario to get you charged:

> - A development data factory is created and configured with Azure Repos Git. All developers should have permission to author Data
>   Factory resources like pipelines and datasets.
> - A developer [creates a feature branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#creating-feature-branches)
>   to make a change. They debug their pipeline runs with their most
>   recent changes. For more information on how to debug a pipeline run,
>   see [Iterative development and debugging with Azure Data
>   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/iterative-development-debugging).
> - After a developer is satisfied with their changes, they create a pull request from their feature branch to the master or collaboration
>   branch to get their changes reviewed by peers.
> - After a pull request is approved and changes are merged in the master branch, the changes get published to the development factory.
> - When the team is ready to deploy the changes to a test or UAT (User Acceptance Testing) factory, the team goes to their Azure Pipelines
>   release and deploys the desired version of the development factory to
>   UAT. This deployment takes place as part of an Azure Pipelines task
>   and uses Resource Manager template parameters to apply the appropriate
>   configuration.
> - After the changes have been verified in the test factory, deploy to the production factory by using the next task of the pipelines
>   release.

To automate the merge from `master` branch to `adf_publish` branch in a CI build which runs on master, you can look at [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#merge-a-feature-branch-to-master). This merges from feature to master, but you will do the opposite.

Comment: I am missing something here.. Exactly this step "After a pull request is approved and changes are merged in the master branch, the changes get published to the development factory." is the one I am missing. I need to programmatically publish the changes to the adf_publish branch. From that I have my own release pipeline in Azure Devops that acts upon the adf_publish branch, meaning that it picks it, it does all the ARM template substitutions and then deploys is to the Test, Acceptance and Production stages, exactly how explained in the guide. Am I setting something wrongly?

Comment: Not sure if I could follow you. What are you missing or what is the problem/error you are getting in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#set-up-an-azure-pipelines-release ?

Comment: No I get no error.. my setup is the following, I have my repo containing ADF code and other code (sql for example). When I merge something into master my CD release pipeline takes the SQL code and deploys it to the Test environment. What happens to the ADF code? Stays in Master, until you go into ADF portal and click on the Publish button to merge Master into Adf_Publish. When that happens a 2nd pipeline will be triggered (cause listening on the Adf_Publish) will do all the tricks explained in the documentation with the ARM Template and deploy to different stages.

Comment: So.. everything is automated. Except that Publish button :) I need to automate that too, either with some step in Azure Devops pipeline or through powershell. Hope I could explain myself properly but if not please don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: This deploys from the git publish branch. So, someone needs to push to that branch either by publishing from a different ADF like from dev/test environment or merging from some other branch :).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/media/continuous-integration-deployment/continuous-integration-image12.png

Comment: Correct! So publishing from the Dev/Test ADF (or from Master) into the adf_publish branch happens through..?

Comment: You can probably look at automating the merge from master branch to adf_publish branch from a CI build which runs on master. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#merge-a-feature-branch-to-master This merges from feature to master, but you will do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

@Tarta, there is plenty of things blended up here.
I don't want to answer everything here, just let me focus on the tool that you tried to use (azure.datafactory.tools), which means - the first original issue.
Looking at the screenshot of log:
[image]
There are no objects found by PowerShell module, which likely means you provided the wrong location (folder) to the ADF.
Please, read the [documentation](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools) carefully and make sure you're passing the correct folder while executing `Publish-AdfV2FromJson` cmdlet.
Also, bear in mind, that the tool deploys ADF from code - `master` or another collaboration branch you selected. The module **does NOT care** what is going on at `adf_publish` branch at all. The changes into that branch are doing by ADF service when you click PUBLISH, but you don't have to worry about it when you choose to deploy from code by [azure.datafactory.tools](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/azure.datafactory.tools/) or [DevOps extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SQLPlayer.DataFactoryTools).
Additionally, I hope the page I prepared will help you a little bit to understand the whole concept of deploying ADF from code (not from adf_publish):
https://sqlplayer.net/adftools/

Answer (score 0):

There were improvements made to the Publishing of an Azure Data Factory.

Previously you need to manually "Publish" a data factory from the UI which doesn't go well with the concept of automation.

Now you can use an **ADFUtilities NPM package** (preferably in your build pipeline), which will validate all the resources and generate the ARM templates which in turn can be used in the release pipeline for your automated deployments. Refer to the below link for the complete details and steps to configure the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements

Comment: Hey @tarta , the above solution worked without any issues for me. Do give it a try and mark it as the answer if it helps resolve the issue for you.